# Installing QuTiP on Windows

Tags: python, windows, installation, build

I have installed Python on Windows. When I run the command `pip install build` in the terminal, I receive no error.

However when I run the second command: `python -m build`, I receive the following error:

```
PS C:\Users\sadat> python -m build <path to qutip>
At line:1 char:17
+ python -m build <path to qutip>
+                 ~
The '<' operator is reserved for future use.
    + CategoryInfo          : ParserError: (:) [], ParentContainsErrorRecordException
    + FullyQualifiedErrorId : RedirectionNotSupported
```

How can I fix this?

Comment: if you are trying to install, it would be this: `python -m pip install module_name`.

Answer (score 0):

It looks like you are trying to install a module called `qutip`.

I have never used this module (although it looks really useful), but the docs are here:

https://pypi.org/project/qutip/

in any event, the standard way of installing on windows using the package manager is this:

```
python -m pip install qutip
```

this would install the package to the current version of python...

Comment: Is this the only command required to install qutip? I used that without receiving any error. But when i use the commands *** import qutip
qutip.about()***  i get the following error `import : The term 'import' is not recognized as the name of a cmdlet, function, script file, or operable program.
Check the spelling of the name, or if a path was included, verify that the path is correct and try again.
At line:1 char:1
+ import qutip
+ ~~~~~~
    + CategoryInfo          : ObjectNotFound: (import:String) [], CommandNotFoundException
    + FullyQualifiedErrorId : CommandNotFoundException`

Comment: this indicates an error with the code (and not qutip). So show the code... was this a python file ?

Answer (score 0):

You can try below command:

```
python -m build C:\path_to_qutip
```

This command should trigger the "build" module and subsequently utilize the supplied path to construct the project found within that directory.